# Node.js client page unable to be accessed

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

So, I have set up a server with Node.js. The only problem is that the client-side page doesn't seem to be able to be accessed. This is my server-side code:

```
var HTTP = require("http");
var IO = require("socket.io");
var Server = HTTP.createServer(function(Request, Response){
    Response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html", "Location": __dirname + "/Chat.html"});
    Response.end("<h1> Hello!</h1>");
}).listen(8080);
var Socket = IO.listen(Server);
var UsersOnline = {};
Socket.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("ENTER", function(){
        console.log("A");
    });
});
```

This is my client-side code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        Console.log("A");
        var socket = new io.Socket("localhost", { "port":8080});
        socket.connect();
        socket.on("connect", function(){
            socket.emit("ENTER");
            console.log("A");
        });
    });
</script>
<h1>ABC</h1>
```

"ABC" nor "A" appear on the page. I have no idea why this is happening. Is there any way to use separate pages as client-side scripts?

Comment: Are you not seeing errors with this code? the `Console.log` line should throw `ReferenceError: Console is not defined` as you need `console.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send your html through headers. To send static html, simply get the file and send it separately. Use this example

```
var HTTP = require("http");
var IO = require("socket.io");
var fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync('Chat.html');
var Server = HTTP.createServer(function(Request, Response){
    Response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html", "Location": __dirname + "/Chat.html"});
    Response.end(index);
}).listen(8080);
var Socket = IO.listen(Server);
var UsersOnline = {};
Socket.on("connection", function(socket){
    socket.on("ENTER", function(){
        console.log("A");
    });
});
```